# alsa minimal configuration

Tags: audio, alsa

I'm studying ALSA and I'm stuck with this alsa.conf file

I need the most simplest conf file which can get my `/dev/snd/controlC0` to work

all my conf files (empty confs or some try with pcm.defaults or something like that)

lead me to an error like this:

```
bera@White-Rabbit ~> aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
ALSA lib control.c:951:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:0
aplay: device_list:262: control open (0): No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you change your `alsa.conf`?

Comment: yes, but intentionally...
I've a backup of the old `alsa.conf`, but for study the conf file for a project with `ALSA` I want to write the simplest `alsa.conf` configuration file :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimal ALSA configuration for your particular case would be something like this:

```
hw{type hw card 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all
my minimal conf to get `aplay -l` to work is

```
#alsa.conf minimal configuration
ctl.hw {
   @args [ CARD ]
   @args.CARD {
       type string
   }
   type hw
   card $CARD #with 0 alsamixer work, with $CARD alsamixer lend to invalid argument
}
```

alsamixer need a little more configuration like

```
ctl.default = ctl.hw
```

and set the $CARD variable in ctl.hw to 0